# How to pipe postfix input to a specific script with user and path?

Tags: linux, postfix-mta

How can I pipe emails for a specific user to a script AND that script to be ran with a specific user's login.

I have this in my /etc/postfix/master.cf file:

```
my_transport unix  - n n - 50 pipe
  flags=R user=deploy argv=/srv/www/myscript
```

My script prints `$PATH` and `whoami` to a file and this is what I get

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
whoami = deploy
```

If I run `sudo su - deploy` and run `echo "PATH=$PATH"` and `echo "whoami = $(whoami)"` I get

```
PATH=/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
whoami = deploy
```

How do I make postfix run myscript as deploy user but with it's real path, not the short one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a dirty hack with a new script that I use to call my old script

```
PATH=/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:$PATH
source "$1"
exit $?
```

More info in [this diff](https://gitlab.com/andreicristianpetcu/infrastructure/commit/a1772664d7d6d939f10539aa2f13dfcc2108b90d?view=parallel)

Hope this will be useful to somebody else :D